# Replace special characters in a string using a python dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, replace

I have some strings that have the following characters: `°`,`/`, `.`, and `+`.

In the project I am working on, these are reserved characters and need to be replaced in my `dataframe` column using a dictionary where keys have multiple values as follows:

```
contractions_dict = {
"capital plus":"k+, c+, k plus,capital+,capital +, 
+k+",
"nécessaire fait ":"nf,n/f,n.f",
"numéro ":" num , n°,n °"}

dic_1 = {r'(?<!\S)'+ k.strip() + r'(?!\S)':k1 for k1, v1 in 
contractions_dict.items() for k in v1.split(',')}
C['COMMENTAIRE_2'] = (C['COMMENTAIRE_1']).replace(dic_1, 
regex=True)
```

I used the square brackets to tag these special characters but nothing has changed in my `dataframe` column.

I have some strings that combine multiple characters separated with white space before, in the middle, or in the end.
I have to deal with it as well.

Can you help me to figure out the problem and how can I deal with special characters and white spaces in the same string?

Comment: So for example you want to replace `k[+]` with `capital plus`?

Comment: Are the entries in your dictionary correct? I mean, shouldn't the entries look like: `"capital plus": ["k[+]", "c[+]", "k plus", "capital[+]", "capital [+] ", "[+]k[+]"]`, etc?

Comment: @Lukas yes right. The exact word is  k+. I put the [ ] to assign the + as character

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to provide a [mre]? It should be sufficient to have a tiny dataframe of perhaps one item containing one special character, and appropriately also a mapping for just that one special character. Note that if multiple patterns are relevant, it is probably a good idea to encode that as a list of individual patterns, instead of concatenating all patterns and `.split`ing+`.strip`ing them later on.

Comment: Why do you don't use `\s` instead of  `(?<!\S)`

Answer (score 0):

You can escape special characters like `+` with `re.escape(word)`. See:

```
import re

contractions_dict = {
"capital plus":"k+, c+, k plus,capital+,capital +, 
+k+",
"nécessaire fait ":"nf,n//f,n.f",
"numéro ":" num , n°,n °"}

dic_1 = {r'(?<!\S)'+ re.escape(k.strip()) + r'(?!\S)':k1 for k1, v1 in 
contractions_dict.items() for k in v1.split(',')}
C['COMMENTAIRE_2'] = (C['COMMENTAIRE_1']).replace(dic_1, 
regex=True)
```

For your second question, you are using atm the pattern `k plus` and this is already using an infix space character. This should work.
When you are using space character as prefix or postfix, those would strip away (because you are doing `k.strip()`), so this would not work. If you want to find  `k plus` in `Hello k plus` you need to remove `.strip()` and `(?<!\S)`, if you want to find  `k plus` only in `Hello  k plus` (two spaces!) you have to remove only `.strip()`.

Comment: The escaping via `\` performed by `re.escape` is equivalent to escaping via `[` `]`, at least for the single-character case here. Escaping the *entire* `k` may be unwise if it may actually contain a pattern.

Comment: Thats right, but for sure its more readable with implicit escaping by re.escape(). And it could help on dealing with newlines in the pattern.